# FQL Bug: SELECT-WHERE-IN query errors out if IN part returns empty!

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to run the following FQL:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me())
```

But, this gives the error:

> error_code":604,"error_msg":"Your
>   statement is not indexable. The WHERE
>   clause must contain an indexable
>   column. Such columns are marked with *
>   in the tables linked from
>   http:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/reference\/fql

Both queries are using indexable columns! And, after some debugging, I traced down the IN part. Basically, if the IN query returns empty (in this case "`SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me()`"), you get this error? And, obviously there are some users who don't have an album!

Basically, this whole query should return no result????

Isn't this an obvious bug?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The query is working just fine for me, one application has the `user_likes` permission and it's returning results and another one with no permissions is returning an empty result set.

Try the query [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) with different Applications (if you have setup multiple apps) and if the problem persists file a [bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/)!

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention that I was calling this with multiquery interface. And, I am sending bunch of queries along with this one, and it returns an error. As you said when I ran this query as a single query, interesting...